# edit css for html(bluedict)

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner and I need help.
I want to put a Word between two borders

My Code

```css
#hw {
  font-family: Nazanin;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: normal; 
  direction: rtl; 
  text-align: center; 
  color: #6dbaee;
}

.h1{
  border-top: 1px solid #00bdf2; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00bdf2; 
  padding: 10px 0; 
  line-height: 150%; 
  position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<p id="hw">beauty</p>
```

What should I do to put my word between two borders(like the one in my CSS)?

Comment: Please be more specific, it's not clear what do you want

Comment: i want to lacate (beauty) in two borders with my css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have all you need. Just add the class `h1` to the paragraph element, like so:

```html
<p id="hw" class="h1">beauty</p>
```

Perfecto!

Answer (score 3):

In your example you use `.h1` but there is no class called `h1` in your html.

In CSS these things are called [selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

With your HTML we can directly use the `p` selector to bind the CSS to it.

Note: that this will be set on every `p` element in your document, so it's important to think to what CSS you bind to what element.

```css
#hw {
  font-family: Nazanin;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: normal; 
  direction: rtl; 
  text-align: center; 
  color: #6dbaee;
}

p {
  border-top: 1px solid #00bdf2; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00bdf2; 
  padding: 10px 0; 
  line-height: 150%; 
  position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<p id="hw">beauty</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do everything more simple. Put word into `h1` tag and give him an id. For tag `h1` you should make not `.h1`, but `h1` selector.

```css
#hw {
  font-family: Nazanin;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: normal; 
  direction: rtl; 
  text-align: center; 
  color: #6dbaee;
}

h1 {
  border-top: 1px solid #00bdf2; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00bdf2; 
  padding: 10px 0; 
  line-height: 150%; 
  position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<h1 id="hw">beauty</h1>
```